# Does this number exist?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

Does there exist $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor$ is a prime number for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: A weaker question would be if it is possible that this set contains an infinite subset of prime numbers. I think this is an open problem.

Comment: Like this ... $2$ is prime, $29$ is prime, $293$ is prime, $2939$ is prime; can we continue this indefinitely?  For this start, no, at $29399999$ we get stuck.  But what about other starting values?

Comment: All the integer parts will be [right-truncatable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime) of which there are finitely many, so the answer is no.

Comment: It's a tedious but easy computational task.

Comment: No, we can choose $E(x)$ a prime number of more of one digit

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I think that the answer to the weaker question is yes. If $k$ is any positive integer, the PNT implies that for $n$ large enough we get $$\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}}< \frac{k+1}{k}$$. This means that for $m$ large enough there exists a prime $p$ such that  $k\cdot 10^{m} < p < (k+1) \cdot 10^{m}$. It is trivial now to constrcut some $x$ with the property from your comment.

Comment: So every prime is the root of a "decimal tree of primes", e.g. from the root 43 there are three branches, to 431, to 433, and to 439. Then 431 has no sons; from 433 a couple of branches, to 4337 and to 4339; from 439 just one to 4391. Are all these tree finite?

Comment: Equivalently, as any prime number greater than $5$ ends in $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$, can we add a combination of these digits to some prime number digits to always obtain a greater prime number?

Comment: Actually, to prevent divisibility by 3, digits $1, 7$ can be added at most once.

Comment: @Wojowu Please turn your comment into an answer, so that this question can be closed.

Comment: @GHfromMO Wojowu's comment doesn't technically answer the question, since the starting point of the sequence needn't be a single digit.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I see. Thank you.

Comment: @Dattier What is $E(x)$?

Comment: $E$ is the function integer part, hence $E(1.92)=1$

Comment: Euristically the answer seems a clear no. Say that the first prime in the sequence has length $m$ (so about $10^m/(m\log(10))$ possibilities for it) and we try to add a digit, we have a probability of $\frac{10}{\log(10^m)}$ to successfully land on a prime again, so we see that once $m$ is larger than $2$ the expected number of live branches decreases exponentially and soon will come to an end with probability $1$.

Comment: Does there even exist any constant C > 1 and an x > 0 such that the sequence floor(C^n x) is prime for all n in ℤ+ ?

Comment: @DanielAsimov It's easy to see, without knowing $C$, that $p_{n+2}\in \left( \frac{p_{n+1}^2}{p_n+1}, \frac{(p_{n+1}+1)^2}{p_n}\right)$ and that once the size of $p_n$ is large enough the width of this interval is less than something like $2C^2+5$, and therefore the probability of each branch continuing becomes less than $1$ (again, for $\log(p_n)$ larger that $2C^2+5$). So with probability $1$ all branches will eventually die out.

Comment: @DanielAsimov That question has been asked on this site before, but no one answered it https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436518/ .

Comment: No, it's not the same question, the question here talk about a real $x$ with $\lfloor x\times 10^n\rfloor$ is prime with all $n$ natural integer, and not $\lfloor x^n \rfloor$.

Comment: @DenisShatrov At most twice. 3, 31, and 311 are prime.

Answer (score 13):

(This is an extended comment.)  There couldn't be anything special about base 10, could there?

Notation: Given two positive integers $m,n$, let $m\oplus n$ be the integer that results from prepending the digits of $m$ to the left of the digits of $n$ (in whatever base we are considering).

**Base 2**:  Here we can only append digits $0$ and $1$.  We can't append a $0$ digit to a prime and have it remain prime, since the result would be divisible by $2$.  So, we can only repeatedly append $1$.  But such a process cannot always result in a prime.  Indeed, $p\oplus \underbrace{111\cdots 1}_{p-1\text{ times}}$ is divisible by $p$, when $p$ is prime.

**Base 3**: Again, we can ignore the digit $0$, due to 3-adic considerations.  We can also ignore the digit $1$, due to 2-adic considerations.  This only leaves us with the ability to append the digit $2$ repeatedly, which leads to a similar contradiction as at the very end of the base 2 case.

**Base 4**: We can ignore the digits $0$ and $2$, due to 2-adic considerations.  Looking 3-adically, we see that $n\oplus 1\equiv n+1\pmod{3}$ and $n\oplus 3\equiv n\pmod{3}$.  Thus, the digit $1$ can be appended only finitely many times (before we reach a number that is $0\pmod{3}$), and hence eventually we must only see the digit $3$ used.  That leads to a contradiction as before.

**Base 5**: We can ignore the digit $0$.  Also, due to 2-adic considerations, we can ignore the digits $1$ and $3$.  This leaves the digits $2$ and $4$.  If $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, then $n\oplus 2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ while $n\oplus 4\equiv 0\pmod{3}$.  Thus, for numbers that are $1\pmod{3}$, we can only append the digits $2$ repeatedly, and this leads to a contradiction.  Similar considerations apply to numbers that are $2\pmod{3}$.

**Base 6**: We can ignore the digits $0,2,3,4$, leaving only $1,5$.  Now, looking 5-adically, we see that $n\oplus 1\equiv n+1\pmod{5}$ while $n\oplus 5\equiv n\pmod{5}$.  So, the digit $1$ can be appended only finitely many times, leaving us to eventually repeat only the digit $5$, which leads to a contradiction.

**Base 7**: We can ignore the digit $0$.  Due to 2-adic considerations, we can ignore $1,3,5$.  This leaves digits $2,4,6$.  Suppose that we have reached a prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  Then $p\oplus 2\equiv 0\pmod{3}$, $p\oplus 4\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, and $p\oplus 6\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.  Similar considerations apply when $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.  So, what has to happen is that we append some number of $6$'s, then $4$, then some number of $6$'s, then $2$, then some number of $6$'s, then $4$ again, etc...

Looking 5-adically, we can get some additional restrictions on the sequence of appended digits.  At this point, additional $p$-adic considerations, for primes $p\geq 11$, give additional restrictions, but they don't seem to solve the problem.

**Base 10**:  A similar analysis, using 2-adic, 3-adic, and 5-adic considerations, leads to eventually only having use of the digits $3$ and $9$.  Moreover, $p$-adic considerations, for primes $p\geq 7$, give limitations on the allowable sequences of $3$'s and $9$'s.  Ultimately, I believe there is no local obstruction (but I could be wrong).  This base seems more tractable than for bases 7,8,9.

Answer (score 4):

A few comments:

a) this problem was mentioned in 2004 edition of R.Guy's book "*Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*". The author's comment indicated that at the time the solution was not known.

b) In 1997 Gerry Myerson [reformulated](https://wcnt.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/wcnt-problems-1996.pdf) original question about infinite sequence of right-extendable (truncatable) primes in the form presented here. He also mentioned that it was easily solved in bases 2 through 6.

c) In 2007 the record-holding sequence was only [14 numbers long](https://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_131.htm).

It certainly seems that this problem (about infinite sequence) is still unsolved. The fact that we can only add digits 3 and 9 is pretty obvious because digits 1 and 7 cannot be used more than twice (modulo 3 argument proves that) - therefore we can assume that the sequence begins after the last time those digits were added.